# SBFT Multiple Leader Ordering Service

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, fault-tolerance, hyperledger-fabric-orderer

How can a Smart-BFT Multiple Leader Ordering Service be implemented ?
What are the implementation changes that needs to be incorporated (refer to some source code) ?
I was looking at https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric/blob/main/orderer/consensus/consensus.go but I do not think that this reference would be enough.
What can be the added pros and cons in this kind of implementation ?

Answer (score 1):

There is currently some work underway to implement BFT ordering for Fabric. The recent [BFT RFC](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-rfcs/blob/main/text/0010-bft-signatures.md) is a good place to start. If you are interested in finding out more I would recommend participating in the `fabric-orderer` channel on the [Hyperledger Discord Chat](https://discord.com/invite/hyperledger).